# Possible to split one JAX-WS service across multiple source files?

Tags: java, jax-ws

Is it possible to split a web service in to multiple classes and still provide a single path to the web service?

I know this isn't possible because of the duplicate url-pattern values.  It sort of illustrates where we're wanting to go :)

```
<endpoint name="OneBigService"
          implementation="SmallImpl1"
          url-pattern="/OneBigService"/>

<endpoint name="OneBigService"
          implementation="SmallImpl2"
          url-pattern="/OneBigService"/>
```

Basically, how do avoid having one monolithic @WebService class?

Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to split a web service in to multiple classes and still provide a single path to the web service?

No. A URI is a connection point to **one** web service (defined by the [Port/Endpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language#Objects_in_a_WSDL_1.1.2FWSDL_2.0)).

> Basically, how do avoid having one monolithic @WebService class?

Well, in my opinion the real question is more *when should I use several Port/Endpoint*? And I would be tempted to answer: regroup/split things logically.

For example, while it make sense for a `Calculator` service to expose `add`, `subtract`, `multiply` and `divide` operations, I would use another service to expose a `getQuote` operation.

Now, you can always split the logic into several classes and delegate to them from your `@WebService`.

Comment: The reason is that more endpoints mean more pain on the client side when specifying services.  The two web services I'm familiar with are Rally and VMware, both with a massive amount of APIs yet still one webservice URL.  This is great for me as a client developer because I don't have to wonder what URL this API is at (still a +1 vote though because now I know for sure I can't break it up :)

Comment: I don't think Pascal answered the question. Rob was asking about putting multiple ports in a single service, not about putting multiple operations in a single port. WSDL does allow for multiple ports in a single service (and thus allows for multiple ports described by a single WSDL URI), and Rob's question is whether such a WSDL can be generated by JAX-WS. I would like to know the answer too!

Comment: ... or instead of multiple ports in a single service, perhaps multiple services in a single WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

You could delegate functionality to a composed class from your web service class:

```
@WebService
public class OneBigService {
    ISmall delegate = new SmallImpl1(); // or new SmallImpl2();

    @WebMethod
    public Result webMethodStuff() {
        // do something with delegate
    }
}
```